# How can I download Ethereum transaction list?

Tags: transactions, raw-transaction, price

I would to some research on how based on the average price one can trade with Ethereum. But I need public transaction prices. How can I get them?

The minute-based price list or even hour is ok.

---

I found here daily prices on Yahoo Finance, but I need higher frequency.

Answer (score 0):

Barchart has a 2-week trial that lets you download Ethereum historical price data for intraday down to 1 minute increments. You can take a look.

See: https://www.barchart.com/crypto/quotes/%5EETHUSD/historical-download

or

https://www.binance.com/en/landing/data

Comment: They do not give CSV, they do not support Mac.

Comment: You can run it on a virtual machine that allows you to run Windows on Mac and convert XLS to CSV or you can use: https://firstratedata.com/i/crypto/ETH, which requires payment. There is always a cost.

Answer (score 0):

Binance offers public historical data via API: https://www.binance.com/en/support/faq/how-to-download-historical-market-data-5810ae42176b4770b880ce1f14932262